# Error creating new post in app/controllers/articles_controller.rb (probably easy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

"NameError in ArticlesController#create" pops up when I try to create new article (post). Haven't even gotten to the point where I have all the articles (posts) appear on one page. I am assuming the error has to do with my controller, or possible my show.html.erb.

Context: This is my first time creating a basic CRUD structure by hand (without scaffold). Appreciate any suggestions!

Code is below:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @article = Article.all
end 

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @article = Article.new
end 

def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
        redirect_to @article
end  

def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

Comment: Please post the full error message. The more info you supply (withing reason) the quicker you will usually get help. Leaving out the full error message makes it much harder to debug.

Comment: I would also use `create` over `new + save` if you aren't going to check `@article.valid?` and have error handling. I recommend putting a binding in your controller method (`binding.pry` -- https://github.com/pry/pry) to make sure that you're both hitting the endpoint you think you are and to take a peek at the params and objects you're creating.

Comment: I just resolved the issue! It was an problem with new.html.erb and show.html.erb that was fixed by changing <%= form.label :text %><br> to <%= form.label "Text" %><br>. Strange...my error for my controller went away when I fixed this. Thank you @Allison for the tips!

Comment: And @Casper I will be sure to post the full error message from now on. Ty!

Comment: That is strange, since the label should accept a symbol and that's the way it's written in documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Next time be sure to include some or all of your form code as well so people can better trace through your code's logic. Glad you got it working!